# publishing ASP,net Web site into Arvixe Hosting web site

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-hosting

that is my first time to publish web site into Hosting web sites 
now i finished devloping of my web site using visual studio 2013 
and start to publish it

1- here i choose to import publish settings file that i get it from the Hosting web site

[image]

2- then add the conniction configuration and vakidate it

[image]

3- then i registered the Data base connecion connection string and validate it 
[image]
[image]

4- but after finish i get the below message 
[image]

could any one tell me may be where i the problem ???

Comment: It seems your connection string is incorrect. Could you please check it again?

Answer (score 0):

Our SQL Server doesn't have the Data-Tier Application Framework (DACfx).
As such, you can't deploy your database along with your files.
Feel free to deploy your files via Web Deploy, then create your database inside WebsitePanel.

You can export the database from your project and import it by clicking on the Database inside WebsitePanel.

Comment: could you please show the steps to upload the Data base into website panel ?